# How to connect to binance WS api

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, websocket, binance

I'm trying to implement the binance specification for their API using C#.
After building the foundation, I tried to reach wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/. But each time I use the code below to connect, the application stops abruptly whith no exception.

```
 using CancellationTokenSource tcs = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            await _socket.ConnectAsync(BaseUri, tcs.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Of course, with BaseUri = wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ and ClientWebSocket _socket . I've seen people talking about a handshake message, but could not find anything on binance doc. I'm i doing something wrong?

UPDATE :
How can i at least debug this ? The connect method doesn't return any data...

Comment: There's an open source library to talk to Binance from C#: https://github.com/binance/binance-connector-dotnet

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'm actually taking a look at their code. They seem to subscribe directly to streams without the "Connect" part. Hope I can annswer myself today !

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link for the solution. I now get a 400 bad request instead which helps a lot !

[ClientWebSocket.ConnectAsync crashes with out any error info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586068/clientwebsocket-connectasync-crashes-with-out-any-error-info)